# Syntax using osmosos with bounding box

Tags: osmosis, extents, pbf

I am trying to extract a region from a .osm.pbf file I have and write the output as a .osm.pbf file. I'm not sure on the syntax however to achieve this result. I have continued from an example I found in another question but so far no luck. Here is what I have so far.

```
osmosis --rb file=germany-latest.osm.pbf -mw file=germany-small.osm.pbf --bb left=8.793491 right=11.5632 bottom=50.5139 top=52.5931
```

This tells me that the file germany-small.osm.pbf can not be found, which makes sense since it doesn't exist, it is the file I want to create. What would be the correct line to achieve what I want?